# ios-fontawesome on UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, font-awesome

I'm trying to use [iOS FontAwesome](https://github.com/alexdrone/ios-fontawesome) to set an icon on a bar button, like this:

```
[self.barButton setTitle:[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FACamera]];
```

and also with this:

```
[self.barButton setTitle:[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForIconIdentifier:@"fa-camera"]];
```

No matter what identifier I use the result is the same:

[image]

What could be wrong?

Comment: are you using the `FontAwesome.ttf` for your button as essential requirement?

Comment: @holex, not sure where to set that...

Comment: the `UIButton` has a `font` property – that can be a good start, but the original author has a detailed description to show how you could do it – if you had read the documentations...

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem` doesn't have a font property, as far as I know. (no need to be caustic, btw)

Comment: yes, it has not, you can change its font via the `appearance` protocol.

Comment: Appearance protocol is not best practice in this case, IMHO.

Comment: that is the official way to do it in Apple's definite opinion (IADO); and unfortunately the _IADO_ is much stronger argument here than the _IMHO_. :)

Comment: Fortunately I found the solution I was looking for (see the answer below). Thanks anyway.

Comment: probably you have spotted that you are doing the job via the `appearance` protocol exactly in your own answer, which you have been against to... just saying, you know. :)

Comment: I take my words back. Couldn't have done it without your kind and precious help. Oh, wait, I've done it... ;)

Comment: hehe, I love sarcarm, but nevermind, you have the solution which you have been looking for, and eventually we are here to help on each other; job has done. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone else ever wonders:

```
[self.barButton setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                  NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size:24.0],
                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: self.view.tintColor
                                         } forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[self.barButton setTitle:[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForIconIdentifier:@"fa-camera"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift:

```
    let filterButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(FontAwesome.Filter), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("filterClicked"))
    filterButton.setTitleTextAttributes(NSDictionary(dictionary: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(25), NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.COLOR_BLUE_DARK]), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = filterButton
```

Answer (score 1):

With the FontAwesomeKit 2.2 API, you can do it like this:

```
[self.barButton setTitleTextAttributes:@{
    NSFontAttributeName: [FAKFontAwesome iconFontWithSize:20]
} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.barButton setTitle:[FAKFontAwesome cameraIconWithSize:20].attributedString.string];
```

Or convert to `UIImage` like suggested in the [FontAwesomeKit documentation](https://github.com/PrideChung/FontAwesomeKit#those-controls-doesnt-support-attributed-string):

```
FAKFontAwesome *cameraIcon = [FAKFontAwesome cameraIconWithSize:20];
UIImage *cameraImage = [cogIcon imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
[self.barButton setImage:camera];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to use easier solution without using attributed texts, look at my library. Cocoa pods are also supported. [Font Awesome Swift](https://github.com/Vaberer/Font-Awesome-Swift)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4, this worked for me

```
let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "\u{f05a}", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(showCartInfoPopUp(_:)))
           
button1.setTitleTextAttributes([.font : UIFont(name: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", size: 24), .foregroundColor : UIColor.white], for: .normal)
            
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = button1
```